# passando um objeto complexo para controller MVC4

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-4

Estou usando MVC4 C#, 
tenho uma tabela que é gerada dinamicamente de acordo com a decisão do usuário, nesse formato:
 gerada por `js`

```html
<tr class="itemPedido"> ' +
 '<td class="col-sm-1">' +
'<p class="codigo">' + $(this).attr('data-codigo') + '</p>' +
'</td>' +
 '<td class="col-sm-4">' +
'<p class="desc">' + $(this).attr('data-desc') + '</p>' +
'</td>' +
 '<td class="col-sm-1">' +
'<p class="un">' + $(this).attr('data-un') + '</p>' +
'</td>' +
'<td class="col-sm-1">' +
'<p class=grupo">' + $(this).attr('data-grupo') + '</p>' +
'</td>' +
'<td class="col-sm-1">' +
'<input class="form-control qnt" step ="0.01" type="number" placeholder="' + parseFloat($(this).attr('data-qnt').replace(',','.')) + '" data-max="' + $(this).attr('data-qnt') + '"' +
'</td>' +
'<td class="col-sm-1">' +
'<input class="form-control preco"step="0.01" type="number" value="'+parseFloat($(this).attr('data-preco').replace(',','.'))+'"' +
'</td>' +
'<td class="col-sm-1 total">' +"R$ 0.00"+
'</td>' +
'</tr>'
```

o que eu quero é gerar um objeto para subir por `ajax` de todos os objetos listado mais alguns objetos que não estão na tabela, como forma de pagamento;

segue o `js` que montei até agora

```js
var data = {
  date : $('#Data').val(),
  clienteNo: $('#ClienteNO').val(),
  clienteRaz: $('#ClienteRazao').val(),
  entrega: $('#Entrega').val(),
  formapg: $("#FormaPg").val(),
  tipopg: $('#tipopg').val(),
  frete: $('#frete').val(),
  processo: $('#Processo').val(),
  obs: $('#Obs').val(),
  traNum: $('#TraNumero').val(),
  traRaz: $('#TraRazao').val(),
  traTel: $('#TraTel').val(),
  produtos: /*?????*/
}
```

Os pontos de interrogação são referentes ao produto que quero montar através da tabela, alguém tem alguma solução para o meu problema? e como eu recebo esse valor na `Controller`?

Comment: Tens algum `form`? nesse caso bastaria `form.serialize();`?

Comment: Tenho sim, mas já que essa lista está sendo criada dinamicamente, o objeto gerado está indo nulo para a Controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloque no formato json a lista

E na controller você receberá um array de Produtos ou uma lista...

```
var data = {
  date : $('#Data').val(),
  clienteNo: $('#ClienteNO').val(),
  clienteRaz: $('#ClienteRazao').val(),
  entrega: $('#Entrega').val(),
  formapg: $("#FormaPg").val(),
  tipopg: $('#tipopg').val(),
  frete: $('#frete').val(),
  processo: $('#Processo').val(),
  obs: $('#Obs').val(),
  traNum: $('#TraNumero').val(),
  traRaz: $('#TraRazao').val(),
  traTel: $('#TraTel').val(),
  produtos:[
      {
        "id_produto": 1,
      },
      {
        "id_produto": 2,        
      }]
}
```

Comment: mas eu não sei quantos produtos foram selecionados pelo cliente, como eu vou passar "id_produto": i

Answer (score 0):

Achei uma solução, não sei se é a melhor:

```js
 $('.itemPedido').each(function () {
                    i++;
                    var prod = {
                        codigo: $(this).find('.codigo').text(),
                        descricao: $(this).find('.desc').text(),
                        un: $(this).find('.un').text(),
                        grupo: $(this).find('.grupo').text(),
                        quantidade: $(this).find('.qnt').val(),
                        preco: $(this).find('.preco').val()
                    }
                    prdt.push(prod);
                })
                var data = {
                    date: $('#Data').val(),
                    clienteNo: $('#ClienteNO').val(),
                    clienteRaz: $('#ClienteRazao').val(),
                    entrega: $('#Entrega').val(),
                    formapg: $("#FormaPg").val(),
                    tipopg: $('#tipopg').val(),
                    frete: $('#frete').val(),
                    processo: $('#Processo').val(),
                    obs: $('#Obs').val(),
                    traNum: $('#TraNumero').val(),
                    traRaz: $('#TraRazao').val(),
                    traTel: $('#TraTel').val(),
                    produtos: prdt
                }
            })
```

só não sei ainda como vou tratar na controller, mas porque ainda não testei.